# Modified question, but nothing seems to be changed

Tags: discussion, bumping, edit-history

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117423/the-annihilator-numbers-of-s-i) seems to have been modified by Bill Dubuque twelve hours ago (or at least this is what the commutative-algebra page shows):

[image: modified 12 hours ago]

But I can't see any change. How is this possible? (I've thought that users rated >10k can see everything related to a particular question: the deleted answers, the edits of these, the question itself after deletion, but in this case seems to be something else, but what?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a question gets reopened it is pushed to the top of the "active" list. This modification, the reopening, is assigned to the last (I think, or at least some) user that voted to reopen. See the [question's revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1117423/revisions) to see the reopening involving Bill Dubuque just at that time.

Comment: I'll just add that in my mind this is similar to [Community user bumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247392) which are listed as "modifications" to the question, but where the Community user didn't change anything.